# Operator observeOn() - runSync vs. runAsync methods

Tags: rx-java2

Can you describe differences between SYNC and ASYNC source modes of observeOn operator with sitatuation when is called runSync and runAsync? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are part of the somewhat complicated operator fusion mechanism of RxJava. I have two blog posts ([Part 1](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2016/03/operator-fusion-part-1.html), [Part 2](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2016/04/operator-fusion-part-2-final.html)) that explain the concepts in general.

In short, the main difference is that synchronously fused sources should not be requested and are by definition already completed. This means when the queue runs out of items, that's an indicator for completion and the hosting operator can call `onComplete` after that. In contrast, asynchronously fused sources should be requested and an empty queue doesn't indicate the source has completed.

The two methods basically derive from the common `drain()` approach of RxJava's operator design optimized and modified to take the facts above into consideration and act according to them.